# Copying Files Based on Folder Structure and Date Criteria in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a folder structure as follows:

```
blob_name
fold1
    2024
        01
        02
        03 and so on till 12
    2023
        01
        02
        03 and so on till 12
fold2
    2024
        01
        02
        03 and so on till 12

    2023
        01
        02
        03 and so on till 12
```

In this structure, the folders `01` through `12` represent the months from January to December. I want to copy files that are considered "new" to the respective folders based on their last modified date.

I'm planning to use Azure Data Factory to accomplish this task. Can someone guide me on how to create a pipeline in Azure Data Factory that iterates through the folder structure, identifies new files based on a cutoff date, and copies them to the corresponding destination folders?

```
{
    "name": "CopyNewFilesPipeline",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "ForEachYear",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "GetMetadataActivity",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('GetMetadataActivity').output.childItems",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "ForEachMonth",
                            "type": "ForEach",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "items": {
                                    "value": "@item().childItems",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                },
                                "activities": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "IfCondition",
                                        "type": "IfCondition",
                                        "dependsOn": [],
                                        "userProperties": [],
                                        "typeProperties": {
                                            "expression": {
                                                "value": "@greaterOrEquals(item().lastModified, '2024-01-01T00:00:00Z')",
                                                "type": "Expression"
                                            },
                                            "ifTrueActivities": [
                                                {
                                                    "name": "Copy data1",
                                                    "type": "Copy",
                                                    "dependsOn": [],
                                                    "policy": {
                                                        "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                                        "retry": 0,
                                                        "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                                        "secureOutput": false,
                                                        "secureInput": false
                                                    },
                                                    "userProperties": [],
                                                    "typeProperties": {
                                                        "source": {
                                                            "type": "JsonSource",
                                                            "storeSettings": {
                                                                "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                                                "recursive": true,
                                                                "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                                            },
                                                            "formatSettings": {
                                                                "type": "JsonReadSettings"
                                                            }
                                                        },
                                                        "sink": {
                                                            "type": "JsonSink",
                                                            "storeSettings": {
                                                                "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings",
                                                                "copyBehavior": "PreserveHierarchy"
                                                            },
                                                            "formatSettings": {
                                                                "type": "JsonWriteSettings"
                                                            }
                                                        },
                                                        "enableStaging": false
                                                    },
                                                    "inputs": [
                                                        {
                                                            "referenceName": "DS_soruce_JSON1",
                                                            "type": "DatasetReference"
                                                        }
                                                    ],
                                                    "outputs": [
                                                        {
                                                            "referenceName": "DS_land_JSON1",
                                                            "type": "DatasetReference"
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "GetMetadataActivity",
                "type": "GetMetadata",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DS_soruce_JSON1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "fieldList": [
                        "childItems"
                    ],
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "BinaryReadSettings"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

Can I have your advice please where I am going wrong?

I tried this but I'm getting the following error

```
{
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": null,
    "target": "pipeline//runid/ef8",
    "details": null,
    "error": null
}
```

Comment: nested for each is not supported in ADF.

Comment: is `01` under folder `fold1`?

Comment: its like as such blob_name
fold1
 2024
        01
        02
        03 and so on till 12
blob name followed by folder name followed by year followed by month

Answer (score 0):

> { "code": "BadRequest", "message": null, "target": "pipeline//runid/ef8", "details": null, "error": null }

**The issue you are facing is because Nested foreach is not supported in ADF because of it you are getting this Bad request error.**

**To resolve this, you need to use another pipeline with Execute pipeline activity like below.**

[image]

- In another pipeline, pass child items from this pipeline you got to for each activity.
- Inside ForEach use Get Meta data activity for folder names to get the Last modified date of file name.
- Then Get the latest folder using if activity and your condition.

Refer this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76051585/18043699) by @Rakesh Govindula  which resolving similar issue of iterating nested folders.